# The sed command in shell won't replace the second matching of a pattern

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command, line

I have the following string and I want to replace (remove) the second word that appears in the string (SECONDWORD). The following line doesn't change anything and just prints the same string. However, when I remove the '123' part of the string the line seems to work.

```
echo "WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD" | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//2'
```

I don't see the problem.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **`sed -r 's/\b[A-Z]+ *//2`**

The `*`, which matches zero occurences, is the issue.

You can see this by playing with the trailing number.  When you have space separated strings that don't match `[A-Z]`, you get matches on empty strings that delimit unmatched strings.

```
    [~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//1'
    123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
    [~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//2'
    WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
    [~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//3'
    WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
    [~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//4'
    WORD 123THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
    [~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]* *//5'
    WORD 123 SECONDWORD FOURTHWORD
```

... so when you have 123 in there you actually want the 4th matching item removed.  Where `'WORD ', null, null,' SECONDWORD  ','THIRDWORD '` are matching patterns 1-5.  It's matching two empty strings around the boundaries of `123`.

You can fix this by using `+` and not `*` with `sed -r`:

```
[~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed -r 's/ *[A-Z]+ *//2'
WORD 123THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
```

Or use the uglier `\{1,\}` syntax without `-r`:

```
[~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed 's/ *[A-Z]\{1,\} *//2'
WORD 123THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
```

But *that* ate a space you didn't want eaten, so used the `\b` word boundary marker:

```
[~/tmp] > echo 'WORD 123 SECONDWORD THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD' | sed -r 's/\b[A-Z]+ *//2'
WORD 123 THIRDWORD FOURTHWORD
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+\s*//2' file
```

Remove the second occurrence of one or more non-spaces followed by zero or more spaces.

May also be written:

```
sed 's/\S\S*\s*//2' file
```